# How to get User id after leave login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, login-control

I develop asp.net Web Form application use VS2015.
I used asp.net login control to identify user.
How can I get the userID after the user have loged in and leave the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ASP.NET Identity. You should be able to access the UserID of your authenticated in user by using `this.Page.User.Identity.GetUserId()`. Be sure to include `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`.

Comment: I am not using ASP.NET Identity. I just use Login Control in my Application